# Find all number pairs in a given range

Tags: algorithm, array-algorithms

I have N numbers let say `20 30 15 30 30 40 15 20`. Now I want to find how many numbers pairs are in a given range.(**L** and **R** given).
number pair= both numbers are same.
My approach:

Create a Map of Array, such that **key of map**= number, and **value**=ArrayList of indexes at which that number appears. Then I traverse from L to R and for each value in that range I traverse in the corresponding arraylist to find if there is a pair that fits in range, and then increment count.

But I think this approach is too slow. Is there some faster method to do the same?

Example: for above given sequence and L=0 and R=6
Answer=5. Possible pairs are 1 for 20, 1 for 15 and 3 for 30.

I am developing a solution, assuming numbers can be upto 10^8( and non negative).

Comment: actually I was thinking exactly as you! I think this is the most simple and fast way.

Comment: If you used arrays to count how many times an element was repeated, it will consume much more size and time than mapping.

Comment: I can use array for small integers. But what if numbers are greater than 10^7.

Comment: That's what I mean. I thing mapping is the fastest way. When I try to solve a question in some competitive contests like ACM, the first thing I think in is map! doesn't waste memory nor time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for speed and don't care about memory there's maybe a better way.

You can use a set as an auxiliary data structure to see if a number was found, and then simply walk the array. Pseudo code:

```
int numPairs = 0;
set setVisited;
for (int i = L; i < R; i++) {
  if (setVisited.contains(a[i])) {
    // found the second of a pair. count it up and reset.
    numPairs++;
    setVisited.remove(a[i]);
  } else {
    // remember that we saw this number, so we can spot the next pair.
    setVisited.add(a[i]);
}
```

Comment: But in the example, the three 30s count as three pairs. Your solution would yield only one.

Comment: It would find all 3. Once the 2nd 30 as found, numPairs gets incremented and 30 is removed from the set. When the 3rd 30 is found, it's added to the set. When the 4th 30 is found, again numPairs is incremented, and so on.

Comment: There is no 4th 30. Let's index the three 30s in the example array {20, 30*, 15, 30**, 30***, 40, 15, 20} to distinguish them. The three pairs are then {30*, 30**}, {30*, 30***} and {30**, 30***}. In other words, if a number occurs _n_ times in the range, the number of pairs you can build is _n_! / 2!

Answer (score 0):

New solution... hopefully better this time. Psuedo C-ish code:

```
// Sort the sub-array a[L..R]. This can be done O(nlogn) using qsort.
// ... code omitted ...

// Walk through the sorted array counting how many times number occurs.
// When the number changes, count how many possibles ways to make pairs
// from the given count.
int totalPairs = 0;
int count = 1;
int current = a[L];
for (i = L+1; i < R; i++) {
  if (a[i] == current) { // found another, keep counting
    count++;
  } else { // found a different one
    if (count > 1) { // need at least 2 to make a pair!
      totalPairs += factorial(count) / 2;
    }
  }
  // start counting the new one
  current = a[i];
  count = 1;
}

// count the final one
if (count > 1) {
  totalPairs += factorial(count) / 2;
}
```

The sort runs O(nlgn), and the loop body runs O(n). Interestingly the performance barrier is now factorial. For really long arrays with really high numbers of occurrences, factorial is expensive unless you optimize further.

One way would be to have loop count repetitions but not compute factorial yet -- leave yet another array of counts of numbers. Then sort this array (again Nlg(N)), then walk through this array and re-use previously computed factorial to compute the next one.

Also if this array gets big, you'll need a large integer to represent the total. I don't know the O() performance of large integers off the top of my head.

Cool problem!